# Why is `ref.current.clientHeight` always possibly null?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to find the height of the component in pixels as its height will be set to 100% in CSS

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";

function Scale() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (ref && ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight) {
//                              ^ error: Object is possibly 'null'
      const height = ref.current.clientHeight;
      setHeight(height);
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="scale" ref={ref}>
      {height}
    </div>
  );
}

export { Scale };
```

Comment: Use null coalescing `ref?.current?.clientHeight`.

Comment: after the ? on the periods, I get the error `Expression expected.ts(1109)`

Comment: That's how statistics work

Answer (score 7):

`ref` is never going to be `null`, as it is `const` and not null to begin with, so `if (ref)` is useless.

The type of `useRef<T>(x: T | null)` is a `MutableRefObject<T>`. Here, `T` is `null`, so the type of `ref.current` is `null`.

To fix this, specify the type that it will be after it is set:

```
  const ref = useRef(null as null | HTMLDivElement);
  // Or manually specify the type parameter
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight) {
      const height = ref.current.clientHeight;
      setHeight(height);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yes this did the trick, thank you Artyer, I would not have figured this out without your help.

Comment: it does fail to compile though `Type 'MutableRefObject<{ clientHeight: number; } | null>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<{ clientHeight: number; } | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'....`

Comment: const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null); did work though

Comment: @Bill That's because `ref.current` is supposed to be a `HTMLDivElement`. Also doesn't seem like `current.clientHeight` can be null

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ref && ref.current && ref.current.clientHeight) {
   //                        ^ error: Object is possibly 'null'
   const height = ref.current.clientHeight;
   setHeight(height);
}
```

This statement should work, but TypeScript often doesn't infer as we expect it to be.

So, best solution (not just some hacky workaround) is to use [Babel Optional Chaining](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) plugin.

Add it to your `.babelrc.js` and you can replace that statement with

```
if (ref?.current?.clientHeight) {
   const height = ref.current.clientHeight;
   setHeight(height);
}
```

It's actually a native TypeScript 3.7 feature, so it works like a charm.

Comment: I am using "typescript": "^3.8.3"